# Documentaries regarding cults

Tags: discussion, research

Hello fellow skeptics!

Please forgive me if this is not an appropriate question. Also feel free to close this question if it is.

I love watching documentaries and have often found it difficult finding documentaries regarding skeptical topics. I often wished there was somewhere on the internet which had a compiled list of skeptical documentaries categorised by subject.

So, my question is: **can you recommend a good documentary regarding cults?**

One documentary per answer please. Also, links to Youtube, etc would be very appreciated!

Comment: Hmm...I've been reading the FAQ and I don't think my question belongs on this site. Can someone with enough rep please close my question?

Comment: Done, I've also converted to CW because it's a list question.

Comment: this should really be done in the chat room --> http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/311

Answer (score 1):

I'll get the ball rolling:

**Cults - Dangerous Devotion**

[Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KItxorTIOw)

[Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_RSdD0BrQA&feature=related)

[Part 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV0ZHiY2c4w&feature=related)

[Part 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edgGThbnKhU&feature=related)

[Part 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uaC19DNkyk&feature=related)

[Part 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bx27izUFFIM&feature=related)

[Part 7](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj9duu7YHbI&feature=related)

[Part 8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EZfe9BTBF8&feature=related)

[Part 9](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b0W2IhRMo4&feature=related)

[Part 10](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp7xxJPFIFQ&feature=related)

Comment: Don't you have more expressive titles than `Part 7`?

Comment: Well, no...they're just different parts of the same documentary "Cults - Dangerous Devotion".