# Making Skeptics less strict or changing the name?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm probably going to get bashed here yet again, but I hope for this site to get a little bit more open rather than [changing its name](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/454/do-you-guys-think-citation-needed-would-be-a-great-name-for-this-site).

I'll give few examples of what I mean that I quickly gathered over just few hours on the site:

- I don't think questions like [this](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/documentaries-regarding-cults) should be closed, even if they don't comply strictly with the scope of [*applying* skepticism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq). To me, that's one good instance of a question that could just be turned into a CW and left as a list of answers as it was intended and as it would pass any other SEN site, such as ask different, had it been about "the cult of apple" or something. *Cults* is a skeptic subject.
- [This](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/is-penn-tellers-bullshit-a-reliable-source) is a question that [did fit](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/604/is-penn-tellers-bullshit-a-reliable-source) with minor modifications on meta. It could simply have been moved rather than closed. Again, too strict.
- And [here's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/how-do-i-find-objective-answers-to-health-questions) another question that *could* have been moved to meta, though it's perfectly fine to be closed as per the current site's *motto* it's also a very valid **skeptic** question to ask!

So, my hope, as usual, is for a broader site. But that's a tendency I have that goes against the (still) current flow of Stack Exchange Network of building strict audiences among family sites. While I think that SEN belief is changing, Skeptics is a clear instance in which I may be bluntly wrong and if that's so then I trust it should just be renamed to try preventing further confusion (from newcomers that is).

Comment: related: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/336/censure-vs-assist and maybe another instance: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/264/the-porn-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main points you are making:

1. Whether questions about "resources" are on topic on main (documentaries, health-questions). We discussed this in [this question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/435/is-the-scope-of-this-site-unlimited), and the answers are clear. More in general, we have had [extensive discussions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions) about what is or isn't on topic.

   The answer, in short, is that we will only accept questions concerning a claim to debunk.
2. Whether list-type questions are allowed. In general they are frowned upon on the StackExchange network, but not strictly disallowed. See for example [this question on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason) which discusses the difference between a good list question and a bad one. In particular, I believe you need to have a **specific question** with **multiple answers**, and not a **multiple question**.

   The Penn and Teller example is a multiple question: you are asking us to debunk many episodes at once. If you have any specific episode in mind, ask a question about that episode or claim.

More references for further reading:

- [Should polls be maintained as Community Wiki questions, or should they be closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/should-polls-be-maintained-as-community-wiki-questions-or-should-they-be-closed/75179#75179)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)
- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: fair enough. thanks for the answer!

Comment: by the way, I just realized... are you asking me to create something around 90 questions about each bullshit episode? :P

Comment: @Cawas: Sure, as long as you are truly interested in 90 episodes, and you can make each one a good question, I don't see why not. :-)